systemd-journal-remote - saving journals on another path
I'm trying to place journald logs from remote hosts on a specified path so I can keep them on a separate filesystem. It fails whether I try to configure it or use a symlink. Hoping someone has an idea of how this can be accomplished.
By Config
/etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf contains:
SplitMode=host
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journal-remote.service contains:
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote --listen-http=-3 --output=/logvol/journald-remote/
The target directory exists. Ownership looks correct to me. I even created journal/remote within it in case journald is trying to use output as a root.
#ls -ld journald-remote/
drwxr-xr-x 4 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote 4096 Aug 30 15:13 journald-remote/

# find . -ls
228589569      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote     4096 Aug 30 11:33 .
228589570      4 drwxr-xr-x   3 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote     4096 Aug 30 11:33 ./journal
228589571      4 drwxr-xr-x   2 systemd-journal-remote systemd-journal-remote     4096 Aug 30 11:33 ./journal/remote

It looks like it should be straightforward, but keeps failing with the message systemd-journal-remote: For SplitMode=host, output must be a directory.
By Symlink
This should be even more straightforward. I restored the default configuration for journald and for the systemd-journal-remote service. Tested that it worked. Then stopped the service and moved /var/log/journal/remote to the other filesystem and created a symlink to that.
The errors are even more bizarre as they seem to have nothing to do with that directory at all.
systemd-journal-remote.service: Failed to set up special execution directory in /var/log: Not a directory
systemd-journal-remote.service: Failed at step LOGS_DIRECTORY spawning /lib/systemd/systemd-journal-remote: Not a directory


Why don't you just mount another filesystem into /var/log? Go into emergency mode, using systemctl isolate emergency.target, deactivate journald, using systemctl stop systemd-journald.service, mount a filesystem into /mnt/, copy all logs via cp -a /var/log/* /mnt/, unmount it, add the new filesystem to /etc/fstab for mount dir /var/log/, mount it using mount /var/log and reboot. You could make it a bit more better, when adjusting certain target requirements, so that /var/log/ is needed for basic.target.
